# modify the Joomla sef URLs for a bad coded component

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla

Good day all, today a client is arrived with a already running Joomla! site, they have some custom content on this site and it has been done by using PHP code directly into some pages, the result is that there is a single Joomla! page, that when requested with a `GET` param is showing different content.
The URLs are something like this:

```
www.example.com/catalog/product-category/product-details.html?intid=1234&name=889-abc-456
```

what I'd like to obtain is to have URLs like:

```
www.example.com/catalog/product-category/product-details/1234/889-abc-456/
```

and I'd like to obtain this by editing the .htaccess file, to avoid touching the code of the site.

is that possible without braking everything considering that .htacces is been modified by Joomla! ?

actually, I've something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST|HEAD)\ /product-details\.html\?intid=([^&]+)&name=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /product-details/%2/%3/? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?product-details/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /product-details.html?intid=$1&name=$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Editing the htaccess file for Joomla URL is not a good idea. Instead of doing changes in htaccess which are more complicated you can take look at router file of the component. Check more details here https://docs.joomla.org/Supporting_SEF_URLs_in_your_component